# SSIS - pulling data from data from database and passing data to webservice

Tags: ssis

I am new to SSIS. I want to basically create tasks in SSIS to do the following

1. Create a task to pull data from a table
2. Create a task to call Webservice. Basically I need to call the webservice couple of times to get the job done. Following are the steps.
   a. Call a webservice to get a session token
   b. Call a webservice to get a session service token by passing session token that you get in step 1
   c. Call a webervice method by passing the service token as well as uploading the data.
   d. Call a webservice to end the session

What is the best possible way to do it?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you opened BIDS yet? Have you looked at this? https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3272/example-using-web-services-with-sql-server-integration-services/

Comment: Yes. I have opened Bids in Visual studio 2008. I can see webservice task as well

Comment: So you need a script task to do 2a and 2b, and the result of this will be a session service token saved to an SSIS variable. Try that much. The web service task is only useful for very basic operations so please disregard my prior comment. Then you use a data flow component and inside that you have a data source and a script destination. Your first task is to complete 2a, 2b in a script task and save the result to an SSIS variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick for your inputs. I have one more question. After completed 2a and 2b , you have mentioned use a data flow component and inside that you have a data source and a script destination. So can i in the dataflow component make a webservice call and push the data. Also what I understand is that I can make webserice calls in script tasks as well.

Comment: If you are extracting many rows of data you need to do that in a data flow. You extract the rows of data with a data source then you 'pipe' that into a script destination. Inside the script destination you process the rows one at a time and call the web service for each row.

Comment: If you are only processing _one_ row than you can just load that single row into a SSIS variable in an execute SQL task then use a script task to send it and you don't need a data flow. You only need the data flow if you are processing many rows.

Comment: Hi Nick,  I need to do three things 1.  first extract all the data that meets a specific criteria from my database 2. Call a web service to obtain the session key. 3. Call a web service to upload the data extracted from step 1 and pass the session key. The limitation of the web service is that it can upload only one row at a time. So i have to loop through my recordset and call the webservice by passing one row at a time

Comment: For every row you use the same session key right? So you get the session key in a script task just once at the start (step 2). The next task is a data flow task. Inside that data flow task you have a source (Step 1 - extract the data) That source feeds into a script destination that calls the web service one row at a time (3)

Comment: So your very first task is to drop a script task into your package and research how to use that to call a web service to get the session token and session service token. then use a message to print that. Then extend this script task to save the session service token to an SSIS variable (that you created beforehand).

Comment: Once you've done that drop a data flow task on the page and put a workflow in so that the dataflow happens after the script task.

Comment: I strongly suggest you first download a web service testing tool like this one https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo or this one https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en and experiment with manually retrieving the token first. This is a non trivial project and doing it inside SSIS adds a lot of complexity. Are you comfortable programming in C# if not then I don't think this is for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a data flow task for 1 to get the data.  Then for 2, you can do that in a script task for a and b, you can use either c# or vb. This is pretty much just programming. Then step c, it's not very clear what you do here with the data. Potentially you use a data flow task connected to the script task you created for step a and b. In the data flow you do the uploading. Then you create another script task for step d and it connects to the data flow task you created for step c.

Comment: Do I need to stage the data after step 1. Cant I use a webservice task for step 2.

Comment: You probably need to stage the data, you can either output to a csv file or a table in a OLE data base. You then upload that data in 2.c. The web service task in SSIS is to send a web service request then get some data back, you then use the data in following flow. Your description looks not like this kind of application, so maybe put in a script task.

Comment: To be honest, SSIS is all about data, so you should try put non data related stuff ( session token etc ) outside the ssis. E.g. you do your session token stuff etc (not sure how, depending on your application and environment), after that finishes, trigger the ssis package, which just do the download or upload stuff.